Would auto-update policies have contained the Crowdstrike outage?
A global outage was caused when Crowdstrike pushed a bad content file. That's well-covered in many other places so I won't elaborate on that.
What I'm interested in is whether company policies to delay automatic updates would have contained the outage.
Crowdstrike has a way to set policies to limit the Falcon sensor version to n-1, n-2, or even a specific build.  So you can assign a test group to get the most recent sensor version and your production groups to get a slightly earlier version.
This is a common practice used for other types of patching, such as for Windows updates.  I understand that the pace is necessarily faster for information security products, but perhaps some form of vetting might have been possible.
The file that caused the problem is classified as a "content file", and so it's possible that it wouldn't have been prevented by sensor update policies.
On the other hand, Dave Plummer's Youtube video suggested that Crowdstrike was using content updates to patch the sensor code without having to go through Microsoft's driver approval process every time.   And the sensor version numbers do appear to increase fairly rapidly.  So it's also possible that the policies also control content updates.
So, can we say if a Crowdstrike customer had set up a procedure to test machines against sensor updates before approving them for general release within their company, that the outage could have been contained to test group(s)?

If it would have worked (answers suggest it wouldn't), a naive implementation runs the risk that when a new, fixed version is released, an "n-1" system would now download the broken version... versions would need to be markable as "never use" and an "n-1" system wait (at "n-2") until a safe "n-1" was available.

I have seen a post on Twitter by a Crowdstrike customer saying that their delayed update policy did not have effect in this case. I was unable to find the exact post but here is another one: https://x.com/christian_tail/status/1814375422328709281 and here is a comment about that under the video from the question: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wAzEJxOo1ts&lc=UgzZuFz9qTuOLEwc_OR4AaABAg

I haven't seen the details, but did the update crash every single computer it was applied on? Or did it depend on other factors (exactly version of Windows, other drivers/software present, specific devices, specific CPU...)?

@jcaron AIUI, it was every system it was applied on, which was in turn every system that was running the CrowdStrike kernel components.

I'm wondering how long has the vendor been pushing updates to clients without self-testing. This issue would have been caught with a single local test, right??

There is one company where the outage was contained because the update was deployed to the DNS servers first.

@SimonRichter Cool - so fortunately all others were unable to locate the download source :)

@AustinHemmelgarn: Every Windows system it was applied on (apparently the bug was only present in the Windows version).

@Vikki It was weird. Some of my servers crashed but booted back up anyway (got the unexpected shutdown reason prompt after logging in).

Spoke with their support and Falcon versions do not delay content updates, so those with n-1 were still impacted.

Probably not, due to who the application owners typically are and CrowdStrike and security products in general update philosophy.
These products usually self-update frequently, with almost no formal communication. This is (subjectively) different from a generic application major or minor binary update.
The vendors, and their counterparts at organizations aren't disciplined ITIL practitioners and never will be ...
About seven years ago I was on a similar incident with Trend Micro. They released an update that cratered every Windows cluster we had due to it interfered with lookups for the Cluster Name Object. We were on a conference call with 70 people.
When Microsoft called in, they told us right away that several other customers with the same product had the same problem...
Fortunately not as many organizations had that product.

This is not a traditional product where the customer plans and prepares for updates by mitigating risk and identifying contingencies. This product is co-managed by the vendor, and they are taking actions that the customer is unaware of.
In a sense, this is more of a service than a product. Concerns about implementations and management should be reinforced by contract, or by selecting a different solution or service.

Worth noting that the offending update was a file that is intended to gather routine information for analysis (basic threat telemetry). Also the component that failed was far back in the release and distribution process, and was in fact the component that was supposed to validate that the file contained the correct information. So the validation mechanism designed specifically to prevent this failure failed in the completely wrong way.
https://www.crowdstrike.com/falcon-content-update-remediation-and-guidance-hub/

Information surfaced in the weeks since the incident have resulted in modest changes to how updates are deployed, including the capability to actually manage the process.
However a more interesting reveal is that the application was/is not in the current state capable of identifying and rolling back this failed update, and likely many other types of failures. The vendor is engaging multiple firms for reviewing the various mechanics of the endpoint architecture and update process.
Probably worth noting that the endpoint is a fraction of their total technology estate compared to traditional security vendors. This is due to the amount of infrastructure they own in AWS (both for customer data streams and an extensive API infrastructure) and the data that they mine from it.
https://www.darkreading.com/cyber-risk/crowdstrike-will-give-customers-control-over-falcon-sensor-content-updates

Conventional wisdom is usually that malware rules databases should be distributed widely fast, so that someone can't sneak malware past a system that's outdated -- which might be easier if someone is able to compare the new rules with the old rules and knows that most systems are still on the old rules.  My wisdom, however, is that anti-malware has caused more problems (via false positives and other means) than it has ever solved.

Given that this incident alone indicated three distinct systemic failures, I don't think we can rely on their internal process for anything.  To be clear: (1) they created a bad update (2) They released an un-tested update into the wild (3) Their own core software was unable to handle a bad update without crashing.   None of these failures are truly acceptable, in my book.

@Miral: this update is not about "content". Content updates aren't fatal and have a backout. This is lack of discipline and a mistake that should never have occurred.

@MikeB  I find it hard to believe they didn't do any testing at all.  I also get the feeling that since the bad file was mostly zeroes, there's a problem in the toolchain that released it.  In that scenario, they tested something, but when it came to pushing that final button, something else was spat out.   The truly unforgivable failure is the 3rd one.,

@Miral in this case, the update WAS the (unintentional) "malware"   The running software should not have died badly on being fed some bad input.   And it should not have taken out the whole OS.

Oh, definitely. They should have done more testing on their driver to ensure that it didn't choke on bad input files. I was just pointing out why they probably felt justified in ignoring the delayed rollout settings. (While not really agreeing with it.)

The vendors [...] aren't disciplined ITIL practitioners and never will be - just pass a law that makes them liable for any damages caused by bad design or technical errors in their products, and they'll be in an instant.

@Haukinger: never happen. No one wants any regulation or consequences for IT. Look up the recent large breaches, very small fines and court losses. Up until this outage, requiring an organization to purchase and implement CrowdStrike (which is expensive) as a result of an incident was one of the more significant disincentives for poor conduct or incompetence.

@GregAskew: agreed, yet - in my experience - writing software in regulated areas (medical devices, aviation) is much more fun and feels much less chaotic and more productive than elsewhere
